# Property of abelian groups without using Lagrange's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, abelian-groups

I need to prove the following without using Lagrange's Theorem:

Show that for an abelian group $G$, $\forall \; a \in G:$
$a^{o(G)}=e$ .

This is a generalization of the Euler-Phi Theorem.

So I looked at the proof I have for the Euler-Phi theorem, which shows that $a^{\phi (m)} = e (mod \; m)$ by showing that $(\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z})^x = \{[b_1], ..., [b_{\phi (m)}]\} = \{[a \cdot b_1], ..., [a\cdot b_{\phi (m)}]\}$, using the $gcd$ operator. I'm stuck on what set I would use here to prove this in a similar way for $a^{o(G)}$.

Comment: you don't want to use Lagrange's theorem, but you want to use the Euler-phi theorem?!

Comment: Can we use the fact that $G$ is direct product of cyclic groups ?

Comment: @Timbuc: The Euler-Phi theorem is essentially the statement Mikotar wants to prove in a special case. It thus makes sense to see if one can imitate its proof.

Comment: By the pigeon-hole principle, one can easily show that $a^r  = e$ for some $1 \leq r \leq o(G)$. It would then suffice to show that $r \mid o(G)$. But here I really want to use Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the Euler-Phi theorem works by exhibiting an isomorphism in order to calculate $a^{\phi(n)}$. This proof can be done by considering the isomorphism $\varphi_a : G \rightarrow G$ by sending $b$ to $ab$. In particlar, note that 
 $$\prod_{b \in G} b = \prod_{b \in G} ab$$
and see if you can conclude the proof. This last step is where the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian is essential.

Comment: +1 Beat me to writing that.
Indeed, the best way way to see is that $g$ permutes the elements of $G$, and then use the fact that it't abelian in a smart way as you did.